# SQL ENQUIRY In how to Get defined number of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a select statement, retrieve about 1000 record
I want to modify it to return only some records defined by @startIndex and @count
e.g. : If I said @startIndex=20 and @count=20
the result will be : from the 21th record to 40th
  I try to make it, but it take the same time as if I retrieve the 1000 record

what is the best way to do that

Comment: which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQLServer 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH data AS (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM sysobjects),
     ranked AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) rownum, * FROM data)
SELECT * FROM ranked 
WHERE rownum BETWEEN @startIndex + 1 AND @startIndex + @count 
ORDER BY rownum
```

Comment: Thank You Anthony, But what if the ID not unique and I want to retrieve Distinct IDs only, Row_Numbers duplicate data

Comment: e.g. all data without row_number = 100, after using it and using distinct it become about 140 or 150 repeat some records and I don't know how

Comment: You can remove the distinct and GROUP BY id instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically called *Paging*, there are lots of samples if you google for 'sql server paging', for example [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/anthonybloesch/archive/2009/11/09/paging-sql-server-result-sets.aspx).

Comment: Thank You Alex, I have already tried to use the row_number ranking function. but unfortunately it duplicates the records if I used it with Distinct